# Opening file from SD card via Intent.ACTION_VIEW

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sdcard

I know that we can open a file normally from internal storage like this:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "my_file.zip");
Uri uri = (FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, AUTHORITY_OPEN_FILE, file)
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            .setData(uri);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

But I do not know on how to open a file from SD card, which we can pick using `DocumentFile` like this:

```
Uri uri = new Uri.Builder()
            .scheme("content")
            .authority("com.android.externalstorage.documents")
            .appendPath("document")
            .appendPath(directory)
            .appendPath(fileName)
            .build();
DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(context, uri);
```

I tried the following snippet:

```
Uri uri = documentFile.getUri();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            .setData(uri);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

But resulting error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/6331-6132:/haxm-windows_r05_2.zip flg=0x10000001 cmp=com.google.android.gm/.browse.TrampolineActivity } from ProcessRecord{a0ed6d5 9894:com.mypackage.app/u0a169} (pid=9894, uid=10169) requires com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_GMAIL
```

I did grant for read and write external storage permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And `Uri` permission as well:

```
int takeFlags = data.getFlags() & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
context.getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags);
```

A file stored in SD card gives us a `Uri` like this, where `6331-6132` is identifier for our removable SD card:

```
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/6331-6132:Folder/haxm-windows_r05_2.zip
```

I read so many posts on StackOverflow, but nothing help. Can you help me to solve this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "which we can pick using DocumentFile" -- how exactly are you doing this?

Comment: @CommonsWare, I have edited my question. `DocumentFile` has a static method to pick a file from SD card, i.e. `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(context, uri)`

Comment: That does not pick a file from removable storage. That wraps a `Uri` that you obtained from somewhere in a `DocumentFile`. So, where did you get the `Uri` from? And are you saving the `Uri` somewhere outside of your process, such as in a database?

Comment: @CommonsWare, I get the `Uri` using `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`. Next, I save the `Uri` into my database. Finally, I reconstruct the `Uri` to get stream using `getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)`. I know that this method is success in reading and writing files. But I don't know how to open external app to handle the file.

Comment: @CommonsWare, For example, I have wrote a video file into sdcard using this stream: `getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri)`. Then I want external apps to open this file after file was wrote.

Comment: What is your goal of your operation with a file placed on a removable media - load the file into your own app or send a file from your own app to a third party app? 

As a last resort you can create a demo project (as simple as possible) which demonstrate the problem and put the project on [GitHub](https://github.com) or other place. Probably it will make the problem more concrete and clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution for this. `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial` will be thrown when you open a external file using `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(context, uri)`.  This static method is only useful when you pick a file inside `onActivityResult()` method with action `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` or `Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`. When your app is destroyed, the permission to access the file is gone. You **should not** use `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(context, uri)` while working with files that require long time permission. Hence, we need `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, uri)` instead.

To do that so, you **must** access the root of SD card's ID (e.g. `6331-6132`) first. For example:

```
String path = "6331-6132:Video/Iykwim.mp4";
String sdcardId = path.substring(0, path.indexOf(':') + 1); // => returns '6331-6132:'
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/" + Uri.encode(sdcardId));
DocumentFile root = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, uri);

// Now, we already have the root of SD card.
// Next, we will get into => Video => Iykwim.mp4
DocumentFile file = root.findFile("Video").findFile("Iykwim.mp4");
```

Notice that you **cannot** access the file directly like this `Uri`:

```
String path = "6331-6132:Video/Iykwim.mp4";
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/" + Uri.encode(path));
DocumentFile file = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, uri);
```

Or like this:

```
String folder = "6331-6132:Video";
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/" + Uri.encode(folder));
DocumentFile directoryVideo = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, uri);
DocumentFile file = directoryVideo.findFile("Iykwim.mp4");
```

Finally, you can open the file using `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            .setData(documentFile.getUri());
context.startActivity(intent);
```

The worst scenario is when you call `findFile()` from a folder with so many files inside. It will take long time and may lead to crash your app. Ensure that you always call this method from different thread.

Android is getting worst day by day. They have made a Storage Access Framework (SAF) that makes you difficult to manage files on SD card. Using `java.io.File` is almost deprecated since Android Kitkat. You should use `DocumentFile` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This may be very basic but the error message says that you are missing permission

did you ask for `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` ?

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#ExternalStoragePermissions

Comment: I did grant for read and write external storage permissions, and `Uri` permission as well.

Answer (score 0):

yo must add permission in manifest file and for marshmallow or above version of android you add run time permission.
for this view

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-marshmallow-permissions-example/

Comment: I did grant for read and write external storage permissions, and `Uri` permission as well. Read my question again.

Answer (score 0):

> I get the Uri using Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.  Next, I save the Uri into my database. Finally, I reconstruct the Uri to get stream using getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri).

My guess is that you are not calling `takePersistableUriPermission()` on a `ContentResolver` in `onActivityResult()`, before you save the `Uri` to the database. Without this, [you do not have long-term access to the content identified by the `Uri`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html).

Comment: I did that before. This error gives me headache for 3 days.

Comment: I called `takePersistableUriPermission()` after `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` calls `onActivityResult()`.